# Chaining jquery selectors. I put all anchors into a variable, and I want to then select one of the anchors using id

Tags: java, jquery, html

I do this (its working fine I assign width amongst other things to all anchors) :

```
var anchors = jQuery("#myDiv a");
```

However I then want to select a specific anchor from the var, this doesn't work :

```
anchors("#anchor01").addClass("myClass");
```

and neither does this :

```
anchors.find("#anchor01").addClass("myClass");
```

I realize I could do `jQuery("#anchor01")` but I figure its quicker to select from the already reduced elements stored in var. This must be so obvious ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
anchors.filter("#anchor01").addClass("myClass");
```

Of if you didn't mind a little departure from jQuery, you could use `getElementsByTagName()`, and access the element with the ID as a property of the `NodeList`.

```
var anchors = document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("a");

$( anchors.anchor01 ).addClass("myClass");
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tphfb/

---

**EDIT:**

Using the `NodeList` is by far the fastest. [Here's a jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/dom-selectin-vs-filter).

Plus, because it's a "live list" it will automatically update when anchors are added to or removed from `myDiv`.

Answer (score 2):

The ID selector will be quicker than getting all the anchors of a div by ID and getting an anchor by ID among the anchors. Use the ID selector, and only optimize when you've measured that something had a performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

`anchors.find()` finds descendants of the matched elements. If you want to filter the results, you can use `anchors.filter('#anchor01')`.

However in this instance, it's better just to use the id selector directly. This:

```
jQuery("#anchor01").addClass("myClass");
```

...is much shorter and precise than this...

```
var anchors = jQuery("#myDiv a");
anchors.filter("#anchor01").addClass("myClass");
```

Both examples get you the element you want. However, as an example a math professor once mentioned: you can use a lot of toilet paper to get the job done, and it'll work, but you're just wasting toilet paper.